# Phoenix framework Generate random string using the controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to generate a token and insert it to my mysql db, this is the current code, im just passing '123'. mix phoenix.gen.secret can generate random string how can i use it to my controller?

```
def create(conn, %{"token" => token_params}) do
token_params = Map.merge(token_params, %{"value" => "123"})

changeset = Token.changeset(%Token{}, token_params)

case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, token} ->
    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
    |> put_resp_header("location", token_path(conn, :show, token))
    |> render("show.json", token: token)
  {:error, changeset} ->
    conn
    |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    |> render(MyApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
  end
```

end

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1`, which `mix phoenix.gen.secret` [uses internally](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/3b9fca11b6a4d6a61ac3ca9163b876e9cdd11dc7/lib/mix/tasks/phoenix.gen.secret.ex#L26):

```
iex(1)> length = 32
32
iex(3)> :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
"YiX2oINVqVWCCQZdmESBN44OxcErAFR4"
iex(4)> :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
"ka2PSR9cHYSlD6fhdMpnGHgTVA7AoDwN"
```

Comment: i added `defp random_string(length)` in my controller, how can i call random_string in the my Map.Merge?

Comment: itried `token_params = Map.merge(token_params, %{value: Token.random_string(32) })` and return a error `function MyApp.Token.random_string/1 is undefined or private
`

Comment: @JAlcantara `Map.merge(token_params, %{"value" => random_string(32)})`? It's more appropriate to use `Map.put` here though: `Map.put(token_params, "value", random_string(32))`.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Ecto](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html)?

> Ecto.UUID.generate |> binary_part(16,16)

Answer (score 2):

Phoenix has the built-in [`Phoenix.Token`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html) module to generate a Token, which will allow you to verify the authenticity of a token without even hitting the database. For example, if you want to generate a token for a specific user:

```
# Generate a token for a given user_id
user_id = # get id of current user
token = Phoenix.Token.sign(MyApp.Endpoint, "user", user_id)

# Later, verify and decode the token,
# and assert that it matches the expected user_id
user_id = # get id of current user
{:ok, ^user_id} = Phoenix.Token.verify(MyApp.Endpoint, "user", token)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that approach, and I want to insert the generated token to my database is it possible in that approach?

Comment: Yes, you can additionally insert the token into the database, but depending on your exact use case it might not be necessary. You need to store tokens in the DB for example to be able to revoke them.